# Close notice is removed when inline-loading an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, closed-questions

Steps to reproduce:

- Find a closed / on hold question
- Have the question edited (e.g. by having someone else do it)
- Click the "this question has been edited" notice

What happens: The question is updated, but the close notice disappears. It looks like the question has never been closed.

Obviously, the close reason should not be removed when the question is reloaded.

Comment: @Mat Thanks. (Eh, this bug is *that* old?)